# TinyMCE запретить использовать strong

Tags: tinymce

Знающие люди, подскажите, сейчас в редакторе при нажатии кнопки, отвечающей за тег b ставится тег strong, что совсем не устраивает. Как поправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При инициализации скрипта TinyMCE используйте параметр extended_valid_elements: "b"

```
<script type="text/javascript">
tinyMCE.init({
    mode : "textareas",
    extended_valid_elements: "b"
 });
</script>
```

Или в xconfig.js поправить strong/b на strong,b

Comment: Апвоут, но я бы всё-таки пояснил, что в современном семантическом вебе рекомендовано делать это именно через strong.